# UWP Navigation Pane go back button not working

Tags: c#, .net, xaml, xamarin, uwp

I'm learning UWP and trying to implement GO BACK button in a navigation pane. I put go-back button under a RelativePanel right below menu button. The below is my current XAML page:

```
<Page
    x:Class="LearningUWP.MainPage"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:local="using:LearningUWP"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:muxc="using:Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}">
    <Grid Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}" >
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
            <RowDefinition Height="*" />
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RelativePanel>
            <Button Name="Menu" FontFamily="Segoe MDL2 Assets" Content="&#xE700;" FontSize="36" Click="Menu_Click"></Button>
            <Button RelativePanel.Below="Menu" Style="{StaticResource NavigationBackButtonNormalStyle}" Name="Back" FontSize="36" Click="Back_Click"></Button> 
        </RelativePanel>
        <SplitView Name="MySplitView"
                   Grid.Row="1"
                   DisplayMode="CompactOverlay"
                   OpenPaneLength="200"
                   CompactPaneLength="56"
                   HorizontalAlignment="Left">
            <SplitView.Pane>
                <ListBox SelectionMode="Single"
                         Name="IconsListBox"
                         SelectionChanged="IconsListBox_SelectionChanged"
                         >
                    <ListBoxItem Name="ShareListBoxItem">
                        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" >
                            <TextBlock FontFamily="Segoe MDL2 Assets" FontSize="36" Text="&#xE72D;"/>
                            <TextBlock Text="Share" FontSize="24" Margin="20, 0, 0, 0"/>
                        </StackPanel>
                    </ListBoxItem>
                    <ListBoxItem Name="FavoritesListBoxItem" >
                        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" >
                            <TextBlock FontFamily="Segoe MDL2 Assets" FontSize="36" Text="&#xE734;"/>
                            <TextBlock Text="Favorites" FontSize="24" Margin="20, 0, 0, 0"/>
                        </StackPanel>
                    </ListBoxItem>
                </ListBox>
            </SplitView.Pane>
            <SplitView.Content>
                <TextBlock Margin="50, 0, 0, 0" Name="ResultTextBlock"/>
            </SplitView.Content>
        </SplitView>
    </Grid>
</Page>
```

And the XAML's code-behind:

```
namespace LearningUWP
{
    public sealed partial class MainPage : Page
    {
        public MainPage()
        {
            this.InitializeComponent();
        }
        private void Menu_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            MySplitView.IsPaneOpen = !MySplitView.IsPaneOpen;
        }
        private void IconsListBox_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            if (ShareListBoxItem.IsSelected)
                ResultTextBlock.Text = "shared";
            else if (FavoritesListBoxItem.IsSelected)
                ResultTextBlock.Text = "Favorites";
        }
        private void Back_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            if (this.Frame.CanGoBack)
                this.Frame.GoBack();
        }}}
```

For some reason, after I click the Go back button, it doesn't work as expected, and what is more, I find `this.Frame.CanGoBack = false`. 
How to solve it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the code that you have posted we can see that `this.Frame` is actually the refering to the *root* frame of the application, which at the moment has only navigated to a single page (`MainPage`) (As defined in your **App.xaml.cs**). Thus there is no page that it can go back to (`this.Frame.CanGoBack = false`).

---

*A little in depth explanation :*

If you go into **App.xaml.cs** file in your project, in the `OnLaunched()` method you will find the following code :

```
rootFrame.Navigate(typeof(MainPage), e.Arguments);
```

Here the application, after launch will navigate the `rootFrame` to the `MainPage`.

When you use `this.Frame` from your `MainPage` it actually refers to the `rootFrame`, which at this moment has only navigated to the `MainPage`, *thus it does not have any page that it can go back to* , hence `this.Frame.CanGoBack = false`.

---

**Solution :**

When you use a `SplitView`, in the content you should specify a `Frame` which you can use to navigate between different pages . Thus your app will look something like this :

Here Red rectangle is used to show the `rootFrame` where as Blue is used to show the `Frame` which you have to define in your `SplitView` content. 
[image]

For this, you need to make minor modifications to your code something like this :

**XAML**

```
<Page
 .....
 .....
   <SplitView Name="MySplitView"
    .....>
       <SplitView.Pane>
         .....                   
        </SplitView.Pane>
        <SplitView.Content>
           <Frame x:Name="appFrame"></Frame>
        </SplitView.Content>
   </SplitView>    
</Page>
```

**C#**

```
private void IconsListBox_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
{
    if (ShareListBoxItem.IsSelected)
       appFrame.Navigate(typeof(page1));//navigating to page1
    else if (FavoritesListBoxItem.IsSelected)
       appFrame.Navigate(typeof(page2));//navigating to page2
}
private void Back_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
   if (appFrame.CanGoBack)
      appFrame.GoBack();
}
```

Hope this helps..!